# How do i fix this Java related minecraft problem?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffb57933033, pid=3284, tid=5140
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x43033]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid3284.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

I am using a intel core i5 processor, and the link to the other article didnt really help me.

Comment: Can you explain I am not understanding and the other article didnt help.

Comment: @TaylorBarnes other one explicitly states that **your graphics card does not support newer versions of Minecraft.** [Also guys good night, 6 am here]

Comment: @ardaokzal I have played 1.8.8 minecraft version with now problems, then i downgraded to 1.7.10 and added mods and it doesnt work anymore. So how could my graphics card support 1.8.8 without mods but not 1.7.10 with mods.

Comment: @TaylorBarnes - We unfortunately do not offer technical support for modded copies of Minecraft. A lot of the time these questions boil down to a specific configuration problem and/or mod incompatibility - debugging these therefore are difficult and there's no "one method" to solving these problems. Thus they were deemed too problematic for our format - see the discussions about this [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10390/28182). The only advice we can offer is for you to contact the relevant mod authors and explain the situation to them.